# How to concat Java string with .class in Intent constructor?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, concatenation

I'm trying to create a menu with buttons that will launch an activity class given the respective button id (i.e. Home1 button, Home2 button):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_home1:
            launchActivity("Home1");
            break;
        case R.id.menu_home2:
            launchActivity("Home2");
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void launchActivity(String activityName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityName + ".class");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

However, I get "Cannot resolve constructor" when trying to construct an intent. How can I write the intent constructor to dynamically construct the new activity parameter?

Comment: The list of valid constructors is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Which constructor are you *trying* to invoke?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want by creating a method like this:

```
private void startActivity(Class<?> cls) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, cls);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Example use:

```
startActivity(MainActivity.class);
```

Instead of working with `Strings`, you are working with the actual classes (`Activities`) you want to launch.

In your code:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_home1:
        startActivity(Home1.class);
        break;
    case R.id.menu_home2:
        startActivity(Home2.class);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This thing you are trying to do, i.e. moving from names to class objects, is  called Java reflection.

Most of the time you will not need it. A much simpler way of invoking an activity will be to pass 
the intent a class object:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home1.class);
```

But, assuming you know your business and do need invocation by string, here the right way to do it

```
public void launchActivity(String fullActivityName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(fullActivityName));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Note that this will only work if fullActivityName will contain the *full* class name
e.g. "com.bla.bla.Home1".